# Key retention when using different ways to select columns from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I ran into an unexpected (to me) issue with subsetting columns in a data.table. I was trying to use `unique` on three columns of a data.table. The original data.table contained several (>5) columns of which 2 were set as keys. One of three columns on which I used `unique` was a key column. The surprising part was that the results differed when I selected columns using their character names versus when I selected them using .() notation. Here is a little example that replicates the issue that I encountered (NOTE: selecting 2 columns rather than 3 for simplicity).

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(c1 = rep(c("a", "a", "b"), each = 3), 
                   c2 = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                   c3 = rep(1:3, 3))
setkey(dt1, c1, c3)
unique(dt1[, c("c1", "c2"), with = FALSE])
   c1 c2
1:  a  1
2:  b  3
unique(dt1[, .(c1, c2)])
   c1 c2
1:  a  1
2:  a  2
3:  b  3
```

It seems like that column selection using `c("c1", "c2")` notation retains the key by `c1` but column selection using `.(c1, c2)` does not. Is there a way to control whether or not the key is retained while subsetting columns?

A little more context to my problem. I was trying to execute this code within a function which took the data and the column names to be selected as arguments. It was easier to pass character column names.

Comment: would you like to add the outputs of key(dt1[, c("c1", "c2"), with = FALSE]) and key(dt1[, .(c1, c2)]) to your OP to demonstrate your paragraph 2?

Comment: is it because the first method reverts back to data.frame method and so its still pointing by reference to the same memory slot whereas the 2nd method returns a new data.table?

Comment: I think the `unique` call is just obscuring it. You could just use `key` to illustrate the point: `key(dt1[, c("c1", "c2"), with = FALSE]); key(dt1[,.SD,.SDcols=c1:c2]); key(dt1[,.(c1,c2)])` I don't really find the last case surprising. If you're doing fancy stuff in `j` of `DT[i,j]`, I wouldn't expect data.table to infer that a key can be retained. For your use case, maybe you should be using `unique(DT, by=NULL)`